# Split string based on number of commas

Tags: python, regex

I have a text which is splited with commas.

e.g.:

```
FOO( something, BOO(tmp, temp), something else)
```

It could be that *something else* contain as well a string with commas...

I would like to split the text inside the brakets of FOO to its elements and then pasrse the elements.

What i do know is that *FOO* must have two commas.

How could I split the contant of *FOO* to its three elements?

**Remark:** *something else* could be *BOO(ddd, ddd)* or simply *ddd*. I can not assume a simple regex regel of *'FOO\(\w+, BOO(\w+, \w+), \w+\)'*

Comment: So for the above example you need result as: [`something`, `BOO(tmp, temp)`, `something else`]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the string is Python code you can use **parser** for this. If you look carefully at the result you might agree that it's not as bad as it first appears to be.

```
>>> from parser import *
>>> source="FOO( something, BOO(tmp, temp), something)"
>>> st=suite(source)
>>> st2tuple(st)
(257, (268, (269, (270, (271, (272, (302, (306, (307, (308, (309, (312, (313, (314, (315, (316, (317, (318, (319, (320, (1, 'FOO')), (322, (7, '('), (330, (331, (302, (306, (307, (308, (309, (312, (313, (314, (315, (316, (317, (318, (319, (320, (1, 'something')))))))))))))))), (12, ','), (331, (302, (306, (307, (308, (309, (312, (313, (314, (315, (316, (317, (318, (319, (320, (1, 'BOO')), (322, (7, '('), (330, (331, (302, (306, (307, (308, (309, (312, (313, (314, (315, (316, (317, (318, (319, (320, (1, 'tmp')))))))))))))))), (12, ','), (331, (302, (306, (307, (308, (309, (312, (313, (314, (315, (316, (317, (318, (319, (320, (1, 'temp'))))))))))))))))), (8, ')')))))))))))))))), (12, ','), (331, (302, (306, (307, (308, (309, (312, (313, (314, (315, (316, (317, (318, (319, (320, (1, 'something'))))))))))))))))), (8, ')')))))))))))))))))), (4, ''))), (4, ''), (0, ''))
```

Comment: i dont really understand what i am suppose to see. What do the numbers (257, 268, ... ) means?

Comment: Those particular numbers are items in symbol.sym_name. 320 indicates that something is an 'atom'. The parser has also identified parentheses and commas for you. I think you can use a regex to go through the string looking for either punctuation or (320, (1, 'whatever' ..., and having the regex pull out the bits you need. And I should have mentioned section 32.4 in the Python manual.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this regex

```
,(?=(?:(?:\([^)]*\))?[^)]*)+\)$)
```

to split your string in the comas, bot not inside BOO(...)

[sample](https://eval.in/657163)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the [regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) that supports recursion (useful to deal with nested structures):

```
import regex

s = 'FOO( something, BOO(tmp, temp), something else)'

pat = regex.compile(r'''(?(DEFINE) # inside a definition group
    # you can define subpatterns to use later
    (?P<elt>     # define the subpattern "elt"
        [^,()]*+
        (?:
            \( (?&elt) (?: , (?&elt) )* \)
            [^,()]*
        )*+
    )
)
# start of the main pattern
FOO\( \s*
    (?P<elt1> (?&elt) )  # capture group "elt1" contains the subpattern "elt"
    , \s*
    (?P<elt2> (?&elt) )  # same here
    , \s*
    (?P<elt3> (?&elt) )  # etc.
\)''', regex.VERSION1 | regex.VERBOSE )

m = pat.search(s)

print(m.group('elt1'))
print(m.group('elt2'))
print(m.group('elt3'))
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/eMtX6U/1)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you need a list of elements inside `FOO`, so pre-processing it first

```
>>> s = 'FOO( something, BOO(tmp, temp), something else)'
>>> s
'FOO( something, BOO(tmp, temp), something else)'
>>> s = re.sub(r'^[^(]+\(|\)\s*$','',s)
>>> s
' something, BOO(tmp, temp), something else'
```

Using [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module:

```
>>> regex.split(r'[^,(]+\([^)]+\)(*SKIP)(?!)|,', s)
[' something', ' BOO(tmp, temp)', ' something else']
```

- `[^,(]+\([^)]+\)(*SKIP)(?!)` to skip the pattern `[^,(]+\([^)]+\)`
- `|,` alternate pattern to actually split the input string, in this case it is `,`

another example:

```
>>> t = 'd(s,sad,e),g(3,2),c(d)'
>>> regex.split(r'[^,(]+\([^)]+\)(*SKIP)(?!)|,', t)
['d(s,sad,e)', 'g(3,2)', 'c(d)']
```